# How to prevent SQL query from returning overlapping groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a report that displays the number of failed login attempts that happen within 30 minutes of each other.  The data for this report is in a SQL database.

This is the query I'm using to pull the data out.

```
SELECT 
  A.LoginID, 
  A.LogDatetime AS firstAttempt,
  MAX(B.LogDatetime) AS lastAttempt,
  COUNT(B.LoginID) + 1 AS attempts 
FROM 
  UserLoginHistory A
  JOIN UserLoginHistory B ON A.LoginID = B.LoginID
WHERE 
  A.SuccessfulFlag = 0 
  AND B.SuccessfulFlag = 0
  AND A.LogDatetime < B.LogDatetime 
  AND B.LogDatetime <= DATEADD(minute, 30, A.LogDatetime)
GROUP BY
  A.LoginID, A.LogDatetime
ORDER BY
  A.LoginID, A.LogDatetime
```

This returns results that looks something like this:

| Row | LoginID | firstAttempt | lastAttempt | attempts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-05-01 00:00 | 2022-05-01 00:29 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-05-01 00:06 | 2022-05-01 00:33 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-05-01 00:13 | 2022-05-01 00:39 | 6 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-05-01 00:15 | 2022-05-01 00:45 | 6 |
| 5 | 1 | 2022-05-01 00:20 | 2022-05-01 00:50 | 6 |
| 6 | 1 | 2022-05-01 00:29 | 2022-05-01 00:55 | 6 |
| 7 | 1 | 2022-05-01 00:33 | 2022-05-01 01:01 | 6 |
| 8 | 1 | 2022-05-01 00:39 | 2022-05-01 01:04 | 6 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

However, you can see that the rows overlap a lot.  For example, row 1 shows attempts from 00:00 to 00:29, which overlaps with row 2 showing attempts from 00:06 to 00:33.  Row 2 **ought** to be like row 7 (00:33 - 01:01), since that row's firstAttempt is the next one after row 1's lastAttempt.

Comment: you can use `max( firstAttempt, lag(lastAttemp) over (partition by loginID order by firstAttemp) )` which will get the start value you need, unless there are three concurrent attempts from the same login in which case you will also need lag 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use recursive CTE's or insert your data into a temp table and loop it with updates to remove the overlaps.

Do you need to have set starting times? As a quick work around you could round down the the `DATETIME` to 30  minute intervals, that would ensure the logins don't overlap but it will only group the attempts by 30 minute buckets

```
SELECT 
  A.LoginID, 
  DATEADD(MINUTE, ROUND(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2022-01-01', A.LogDatetime) / 30.0, 0) * 30, '2022-01-01') AS LoginInterval,
  MIN(A.LogDatetime) AS firstAttempt,
  MAX(A.LogDatetime) AS lastAttempt,
  COUNT(*) attempts
FROM 
  UserLoginHistory A
WHERE 
  A.SuccessfulFlag = 0 
GROUP BY
  A.LoginID, DATEADD(MINUTE, ROUND(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2022-01-01', A.LogDatetime) / 30.0, 0) * 30, '2022-01-01')
ORDER BY
  A.LoginID, LoginInterval
```